# Let $A \text { and } B \in \text { some } \sigma \text {-field}~F$ show that F contains the sets $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B^{c}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

so i'm having a little difficulty with this question.

> Let $A \text { and } B \in \text { some } \sigma \text {-field}~F$ show that F contains the sets $A \cap B$ and $A \cap B^{c}$

F is a $\sigma$-field if it satisfies the following axioms

(1) $ \emptyset \in F $

(2) for $A_1,A_2,A_3,.... \in F$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i} \in F$

(3) if $A \in F$ then $A^{c} \in F$ where $A^{c} = \Omega \text{\ }  A$

so as far as i can conclude i can break $A \cap B$ into several distinct cases for example.

if A and B are pairwise disjoint then $A \cap B = \emptyset \in F$.
Further if $A \subset B$ then $A \cap B = A \in F$

i know $A=\Omega \cap A^c$ which are all elements of F but for nondescript A and B i have no clue.

any suggestions?
all help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from
$$A\cap B = (A^c \cup B^c)^c$$
and from
$$A\cap B^c = (A^c \cup B)^c.$$

Comment: that makes alot of sense...i feel kind of stupid, cheers for that.